# How to create list of certain criteria from pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame for a fraud project for school. I have a DataFrame with 14k entries, and there are some countries with cases of fraud and some without any at all indicated by a column 'fraud'. This is in a pandas df. How can I create a list of the countries that have no fraud at all?

Comment: What value in the column `'fraud'` would indicate no fraud at all in your dataset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the value in the `'fraud'` column that means "no fraud at all" would be `0`, you can simply use masking:

```py
df[df['fraud'] == 0]
```

This returns the dataframe with only the rows where countries have no fraud. If you have a column that includes the country name and just wanted a list of country names, you could do `df[df['fraud'] == 0]['country_name']` or whatever the column label is for the country name column in your dataframe.

You would replace `0` with whatever value indicates no fraud at all.

---

UPDATE for boolean values:

Since the values of `'fraud'` are `True/False`, you can just use

```py
df[~df['fraud']]
```

Comment: so the fraud column is either True or False but I imagine this same principle works

Comment: This gave me what I needed. Then I was able to pull out the unique values. Thanks @clarked

Comment: Glad this worked. I just update my answer with what you can do for boolean values True or False.